# JSON string deserialisation into C# object

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have the following result from an API call - what would be the best C# object structure to be able to deserialise the JSON string into the C# object?

The issue I have is that the JSON object are actually the name of the brand rather than

```
 "data":{"brands":{"brand":{"name:"Amazon"...etc
```

the api is returning:

```
"data":{"brands":{"amazon":{"name:"Amazon",....
```

Which makes it difficult to create a brands--> brand hierarchy

See below for entire JSON string:

```
{
       "status":"success",
       "code":"1254",
       "message":"Hello",
       "data":{
          "brands":{
             "amazon":{
                "slug":"amazon",
                "name":"Amazon UK"
             },
             "boots":{
                "slug":"boots",
                "name":"boots UK"
             }
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: Which object model do you expect?

Comment: That sounds like your `Data` class (or whatever's representing the `data` field) just needs a `Dictionary<string, Brand>` property called `Brands`.

Comment: A `Dictionary<string, Brand>` is probably the best choice here

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I was hoping to achieve something like RootObject-->Brands-->listOF Brand

Comment: @JonSkeet   thanks that make sense

Comment: @Paul on your recently deleted SQL question you said "why you have to assume we have not tried is not clear" - well many people have not tried and just expect to be able to dump their data on this site and have someone do their work for them. The only way to know otherwise is if you show us. It also helps clarify the problem and your experience level because we can see how you approached the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following structure should be fine, I guess

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string, Brand> brands { get; set; }
}
public class Brand
{
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And use ii like

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJsonString);
```